evaluation of condition does not work as expected
I'm new to pine script.
I want to detect the imbalance of bar 2

I wrote this script:
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © myself

//@version=5
indicator("My first try", overlay=true)

find_imbalance(h1, h3, l1, l3) =>
    var int rv = 0

    if h3 < l1
        rv := 1
    if l3 > h1
        rv := -1
    rv

var label myLabel = label.new(bar_index, high + ta.tr, textcolor=color.white, color=color.blue)

if barstate.islast
    log.info("{0} - cur: h={1}, l={2}, bar[1]: h={3}, l={4} bar[3]: h={5}, l={6}", bar_index, high, low, high[1], low[1], high[3], low[3])

    label.set_x(myLabel, bar_index)
    label.set_y(myLabel, high + ta.tr)
    var int ib = find_imbalance(high[1], high[3], low[1], low[3])

    if ib > 0
        label.set_text(myLabel, text="Imbalance Long")
    else if ib < 0
        label.set_text(myLabel, text="Imbalance short")
    else
        label.set_text(myLabel, text="Bars on\nthe chart:\n" + str.tostring(bar_index + 1))

which produced this logs:
[2024-05-30T18:00:00.212+02:00]: 11,860 - cur: h=5,261.5, l=5,261.5, bar[1]: h=5,263, l=5,261.25 bar[3]: h=5,264, l=5,263.25
[2024-05-30T18:00:00.212+02:00]: 11,860 - cur: h=5,261.5, l=5,261.25, bar[1]: h=5,263, l=5,261.25 bar[3]: h=5,264, l=5,263.25

Values from log indicate, that imbalance could be detected, but label shows text from else condition (no imbalance found)
What am I doing wrong?

Use the log as debug. Do not only log the base data you are working with, log the results of the expressions you have created to see where the calculations go wrong - even though the underlying base data is correct. Also, it looks nice, but if you call a function only 1 time in your script there is not much use to abstract that code into a function. Pine can bite you with certain syntax and behind-the-scenes behavior. if you are new to Pine (which I doubt based on the code except if you copied it from somewhere) then write hard-coded monolith first and refactor when it works.

@karatedog Thank you for that advice! Where can I find out more about pine's behind-the-scenes behaviour?

by using log as debug I found out, that the single line if does not work in the function. Just adding a log made them work :(

Start here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html

Now, put that function code back in the main code and see if it's fixed :D

with log as debug I got my script working :)

If you understand the problem, describe its solution so that it can be shared with other users with a similar problem.
If the problem is not solved yet, I will try to help you with a solution and explanation,
Did you add the script to the chart when there was no bar 2 yet? That is, bar 2 was formed in real time after being added to the chart?
